# C++ Queuing function calls

Tags: c++, lambda, queue

I have a function that queues function callbacks to be executed in another thread.

```
void Queue(std::function<void()> callback)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queueMutex);
    queue.push_back(callback);
}
```

The queued functions are called using this function in the main thread:

```
void ProcessQueue()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queueMutex);
    if (!queue.empty()) 
    {
        for (auto& cb : queue) 
        {
            cb();
        }
        queue.clear();
    }
}
```

I am queuing these callbacks because they must be executed in the main thread. My question is whether it's safe (and appropriate) to chain multiple functions within a single `Queue` call, like this:

```
Queue([=]()
{
    FunctionA();
    FunctionB();
});
```

Or is it better to separate them like this?

```
Queue([=]()
{
    FunctionA();
});

Queue([=]()
{
    FunctionB();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose the first option. In the second version, the additional cost of creating and calling the lambda. Since you use capture by value [=], it can be quite costly when capturing heavy objects.
std::function also affects performance.
The second version uses two std::function copies the lambdas with captured parameters for the call, more memory is used here, plus std::function calls the function using a virtual call and this affects performance. Considering these facts, in my opinion, the first version is better.